# Dynamic 'table' name in LINQ to entities

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

I need to select from varying levels of reporting department tables, i.e. Dept1, Dept2, Dept3, ect. [1] depending on which reporting level the user chooses.  How can I dynamically express the 'table' to select from based on a given string parameter, which is the table name?

[1] Easy points (lets talk) for anyone that can help me out of this, deeper mess than the question exposed.

BREAKING NEWS:  Looks like I'm going with a 'switch/case' construct.  I'm tired of poring over idiotic non-solutions, and the first intelligent one I found doesn't work easily enought (without generations monastic, secluded dedication).  The customer's needs come before mine.

Comment: That's a really bad way to organize data, but I suspect you're getting to understand that now.

Comment: I've understood that since college, but I can't always use my own designs from the word go. :-(

Comment: -1 for unnecessary vitriol and attempted clever phrasings.  Stick to the point, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the EF has an equivalent of Linq->SQL's GetTable yet although I did find [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/613f5cac-5c1d-441f-be1e-ab734f185515) about a possibly future implementation of GetEntitySet as well as a simple implementation you can use I would check it out.

Comment: There is one good candidate solution on that post, drowning in a black sea of utter stupidity and density such as only seen in radioactive metals.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ability to change the schema?  I suspect you are asking this question because you don't, but if you do, it might be easier to have a `Department` table which defines a department name and its ID.  Then, you can have a single table with the entities you are searching for and a foreign key pointing to a department.

So, if the entities you are trying to query are employees, your tables might look like this:

```
Department
------------
ID     int
Name   text

Employee
--------------------
ID             int
Name           text
DepartmentID   int
```

Then your query might look something like this:

```
var Employees = from emp in db.Employee.Include("Department")
                where emp.Department.Name == "Sales"
                select emp;
```

Comment: I can change the schema, but only later, with an incremental rewrite.  I can't change it today to solve this problem.